# Подсчет количества строк в select с группировкой и проверкой флага - SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Имеется пара sql-запросов следующего содержания (часть запроса для простоты опущена):

```
select count(*)
from   ext_restriction er
where  er.proceed = '1'
```

и

```
select count(*)
from   ext_restriction er
where  er.proceed = '0'
```

в принципе всё нормально работает, но выяснилось, что в таблице `ext_restriction` может иметься несколько строк с одинаковым значением в поле `act_id` и нужно преобразовать запрос так, чтобы он работал следующим образом: при подсчете количества строк строки с одинаковым значением `act_id` должны учитываться только один раз, при этом, если хотя бы в одной из строк с одинаковым `act_id` установлен флаг `proceed = '1'`, то они должны учитываться в первом запросе и не должны учитываться во втором и наоборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select highproceed, count(0) from (
    select act_id, max(proceed) as highproceed 
    from ext_restriction 
    group by act_id
) sq
group by highproceed
```

Сначала находим все act_id и берём максимальный proceed - т.е. если хоть в одной строке тут было 1, а у остальных 0 - то max вернёт 1.

Затем группируем по этому значению и считаем количество. Считаем сразу оба результата, которые вы сейчас считаете в два запроса, просто будет несколько строк в ответе.

Ну раз по каким-то причинам надо два запроса, вместо того чтобы нормально посчитать одним запросом, подсчёт 0:

```
select count(0) from (
    select act_id, max(proceed) as highproceed 
    from ext_restriction 
    group by act_id
    having highproceed = 0
) sq
```

Для подсчёта отдельно proceed = 1 можно чуть попроще:

```
select count(distinct er.act_id)
from   ext_restriction er
where  er.proceed = 1
```